# JUnit testing with exception expectations (multiple asserts)

Tags: java, exception, junit, xalan

I'm testing a WeekConverter for Xalan use and wondering what is my test exactly doing. :D

Having the following test method:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void testConvertTwoDigitYearWithWrongInput() {
  WeekConverter weekConverter = new WeekConverter(WeekConverter.Strategy.TWO_DIGIT_YEAR);

  //wrong or empty inputs
  assertEquals("0", weekConverter.convert(""));
  assertEquals("0", weekConverter.convert("abcdefgh"));
}
```

Will this test expect an exception for all asserts, or only for the first assert? If only the first, which would mean that I have to create a test method for each assert, although I'm expecting the same exception in both cases. Can someone confirm my example here, please?

I also have a test for null, which yields a *NullPointerException*. The soft validation is the following:

```
if (inputDate == null) {
  do something and throw NullPointerexception
} else if (inputDate.isEmpty()) {
  do something and throw IllegalArgumentException, since inputDate is not really null
} else if (inputDate.matches(regex)) {
  go futher and convert
} else {
  do something and throw IllegalArgumentException, since inputDate does not match regex
}
```

Therefore the one test method expecting *IllegalArgumentException* with two asserts. But it's obvious that I need two different test methods, not only to respect functionality of JUnit , but also that I expect a throw from two different states.

Comment: Since you're expecting an exception, you don't need the assert equals -- all you need is the call to convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break your method into multiple methods, but if you have many input samples it would be inconvenient.

You can use the following approach instead:

```
@Test
public void testConvertTwoDigitYearWithWrongInput() {
    WeekConverter weekConverter = new WeekConverter(WeekConverter.Strategy.TWO_DIGIT_YEAR); 

    assertFailsToConvert(weekConverter, ""); 
    assertFailsToConvert(weekConverter, "abcdefgh");
}

private void assertFailsToConvert(WeekConverter weekConverter, String input) {
    try {
        weekConverter.convert(input);
        fail("Should not convert [" + input + "]");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {}
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the tests are no longer self-documenting without looking at the test, and can no longer be documented in human-readable form without an AST and guesswork. Keeping them separate allows far better info generation.

Comment: But having a large number of separate tests for different input samples would hamper readability and maintainability, so that you should decide what is more important for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide multiple test methods, since they're testing different things.

The exception will be thrown the first time the converter gets an illegal argument.

You should also test a null input, just to document behavior.

Comment: This is a good point... specially when throwing the same Exception but from different states.

Answer (score 1):

The test is just expecting that IllegalArgumentException is being throw, regardless from where or why it is being throwed.

I recommend you to split it in two tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the creation of the conversion fixture in a separate @Before setup method, and then you can have (three) separate test cases for dealing with null, "", and "abcdef".

If there are more cases to test,
a neat way in JUnit is to use the [@Parameters](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/) annotation and corresponding runner.

Your test class would deal with incorrect two digit years only. Its constructor would be parameterized with an `inputDate` of type String.

The static method yielding the `@Parameters` would return a collection containing `""` and `abcdefg` (and other funny cases).

The single test case would expect an `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class IncorrectTwoDigitYears {
    String inputDate;

    public IncorrectTwoDigitYears(String inputDate) {
        this.inputDate = inputDate;
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testFormat() {
        (new WeekConverter(WeekConverter.Strategy.TWO_DIGIT_YEAR))
            .convert(inputDate);
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
       Object[][] data = new Object[][] { 
           { "" }, { "abcdef" }, { "0" }, { "000" }, { "##" } };
       return Arrays.asList(data);
    }
}
```

The pay off will be higher if you have more than just two cases to test.

Answer (score 1):

Try [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/):

```
@Test
public void testConvertTwoDigitYearWithWrongInput() {

    WeekConverter weekConverter = ...

    // wrong or empty inputs
    verifyException(weekConverter, IllegalArgumentException.class)
       .convert("");
    verifyException(weekConverter, IllegalArgumentException.class)
       .convert("abcdefgh");
}
```